# right to left text in contextmenu

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, right-to-left

I can see all texts of contextmenu and its menuitems and submenuitems on right side, that is Right to Left.

```
cm.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
this.ContextMenu = cm;
```

Now, I use cm.MenuItems[1].MenuItems[0].Enabled = false OR menuSubItem.Enabled = false. Now I see texts of menusubitems on left, that is Left to Right.

I want all text strings to be on right, that is Right to Left.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting a form or control's RightToLeft property to true reverses the
> reading order of elements on a form, but it does not reverse the
> layout to be right-to-left — that is, it does not cause mirroring.
>
> You can create mirroring in code. For forms, you can set an extended
> Windows style to cause mirroring. For most controls that require
> mirroring, you can create a mirrored control by inheriting from the
> base control and setting the same Windows extended style. You can
> create mirrored versions of the following controls:
>
> `ListView Panel   StatusBar TabControl    TabPage ToolBar Treeview`
>
> Some controls are sealed, so you cannot derive a new control from them.
> These include the ImageList and ProgressBar controls.
>
> But there is a non-like thing. When you design a Form and put some
> some controls on it, the appearance during runtime will be mirrored.
> The control that you put it at the right of the form will be shown at
> the left.

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5071/Windows-Forms-and-Controls-with-Right-to-Left-Layo

Follow the source for guidelines.